# No entiendo por qué da el error SyntaxError en este código tan pequeño

Tags: javascript

Aprendiendo a usar funciones arrow me encuentro con un código que pide que use filter,map, o reduce para que la función devuelva sólo numeros enteros positivos. Para ello lo unico que debo añadir es la var squaredIntegers que he escrito.

```js
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2];
const squareList = (arr) => {
  "use strict";
  
  var squaredIntegers = realNumberArray.filter((num) => Math.sqrt(Math.floor((num > 0))))
  
  const squaredIntegers;
};

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray);
console.log(squaredIntegers);
```

Cuando ejecuto aparece: *Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'realNumberArray' has already been declared*
Pero evidentemente necesito declarar al menos una vez realNumberArray, y luego una vez usarlo con filter. Como puedo usar filter en realNumberArray sino?

Comment: Cuando declaras una constante con `const` ya no la puedes redeclarar, ese mensaje es correcto y parte del proceso de validar una sola vez la existencia de la creaciòn de una constante, me parece estas construyendo mal la lógica de tu algoritmo

Comment: cual es la lógica de declararlo 3 veces?

Answer (score 2):

Cuando declaras una constante en Javascript debes asignarle el valor que tomara, ya que posteriormente no podrás hacerlo, estas declarando una variable con sintaxis < ES6 y una constante con el mismo nombre lo cual provocara una excepción debido a que la variable ya ha sido declarada, hace falta que al final de tu función retornes el valor deseado, de lo contrario siempre obtendrás undefined en tu impresión de consola, adjunto el código que adecue para poder obtener el resultado deseado.

```
const realNumberArray = [4, 5.6, -9.8, 3.14, 42, 6, 8.34, -2]
const squareList = (arr) => {
  'use strict'

  return realNumberArray.filter((num) => Math.sqrt(Math.floor((num > 0))))
}

const squaredIntegers = squareList(realNumberArray)
console.log(squaredIntegers)
```